# How to open a file which is in read write execute mode in C (shell programming)

Tags: c, csh

I am trying to create a file, but it is opening in locked mode. How to make it in read write execute mode?

```
switch(choice){
case 1: printf("\n Enter the file: ");
    scanf("%s", file);
    open(file, O_CREAT, S_IRWXG);
    break;
```

Comment: Because you omit O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY and O_RDWR, you are actually opening the file in O_RDONLY mode, for all you also create it.  The `S_IRWXG` flag sets `---rwx---` mode, modified by `umask`.  It's most succinct to write the mode in octal: `0777` if you're sufficiently confident that you won't be attacked.  Or use `S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO`.  But that is still modified by `umask`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument of open doesn't actually have to be one of the defined flags.  If you want it in +rwe mode for all users, just change your code to

```
open(file, O_CREAT, 0777);
```

EDIT: If you'd prefer to use the flags.  Just combine them with the | command.  You'll end up actually passing the same value in, but many people prefer to use the flags.